# How to run Mathematica as a .m file

Tags: command-line

I've created this Dummy.nb file with the code

```
x=2
x+3
```

and exported it as Dummy.m. Whenever I try to run it on the command line with math -run Dummy.m or math -script Dummy.m, a local interactive Mathematica kernel starts up, which is not what I want. It generates this output

[image: Terminal Output]

Ideally, I would want to run a notebook on the command line, and have the output evaluated for each cell, but my reading of this stack exchange makes me think that this is unlikely. I know this is a basic question, but how do I run my Mathematica code on the kernel properly.

Thank you for answering!

Comment: [`WolframScript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html)

Comment: This looks like the common mistake of not making sure cells have been set as initialization cells before exporting to a package. Check your `Dummy.m` and see if code lines have been commented out `(* like this *)`.

Comment: The code was commented out, but then I uncommented it, and it's still not running.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving your commands in a text file, then piping it to math.exe:

> more dummy.txt | math.exe

[image]